# Memory Upgrade Issues

Tags: craft3, mamp, memory, cli

### Problem

Hi all, I have been struggling with issuing the command `./craft gc`. It shows the following

```
Delete all trashed items? (yes|no) [no]:yes
Running garbage collection ... PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes)'
```

the allowed memory size equates to 128MB. I attempted to increase the limit but it still showed the 128M `Allowed memory size`.

### What I've Done

- I have set `'phpMaxMemoryLimit' => '1024M'` in `config/general.php`
- I have set `memory_limit = 1024M` in the `php.ini`
- I executed the command `php --ini |grep "Loaded Configuration File"` which showed the correct path
- I made a `webroot/phpfile` with `<?php phpinfo();` which showed both the correct path, and correct `memory_limit`
- I checked `admin/utilities/php-info` which showed the correct `memory_limit`

### Information

- PHP version   7.3.3
- OS version    Darwin 19.2.0
- Craft edition & version   Craft Pro 3.3.19
- Mamp PRO version 5.3

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have the correct PHP loading in your CLI. You should try [using MAMP’s PHP Executable in your Terminal](https://craftcms.com/guides/mamp-with-composer-and-mysql-on-the-command-line#using-mAMPs-php-executable-in-terminal).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Oli, but I've already done this. .bash_profile has `export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.3/bin:${PATH}"` set already